# Reading a text within my Mac OS X app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

Doing some Mac coding, I have this simple code which always produces null results:

```
  NSString *bundlePathWithFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample.txt" ofType:nil];
  NSString *info = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:bundlePathWithFile 
  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];  
   NSLog(@"results %@",info);
```

I have not code signed in Xcode. I have the *Code Signing Identity* set to *Don't Code Sign*.
Nor have I done a self signed cert.

I only want to read the text of a file, that is part of my apps bundle. Do I have to code sign and provide entitlements even to read files that are bundled within my app in a `resources` folder?

Am I missing something that is not allowing me to read my own apps files here?

Comment: Is sample.txt being included in the Copy Bundle Resources phase?

Comment: @CodaFi, Yes it is set in the targets Build Phase.

Comment: Can you confirm that's file name and the one you're handin over to NSBundle are the same (File names are CaSe SeNsiTiVe)?  Have you tried opening up the Bundle to see if it's getting copied over correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to pass an NSError as the error parameter with the `stringWithContentsOfFile` message? Then with `NSLog` you could get more information.

Comment: @Peteee24, That's what I should have done. Thank you. The error returns: `Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 UserInfo=0x2bdcc0 "The file “sample.txt” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."` which I am puzzled about since it's a regular text file.

Comment: Solved, it should be NSASCIIStringEncoding for regular text files.

Comment: *Regular* is a bold term given the number of encodings e.g. `NSString` supports.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

*Regular* is a bold term given the number of encodings e.g. `NSString` supports.. ;-)

`NSUTF8StringEncoding` should usually work for plain text files but you'll want to make sure your text file has the proper encoding - checking e.g. with the free and awesome **TextWrangler** that'll display the encoding and allow you to convert encodings.